# Find class object from string property

Tags: c++, class, key

Lets say I have a simple class with the following definition

```
class objectA {
 public:
  objectA() {} objectA(std::string aName, int aValue) : name(aName), value(aValue) {}
  std::string name;
  int value;
}
```

And we define two objects

```
objectA A("myObjectA", 1);
objectA B("myObjectB", 2);
```

How can I access at compile-time get access of one of the objects via a key lookup like

```
get("myObjectA")
```

and maybe also be able to set the value afterwards

```
get("myObjectA")->setValue("3") //sets the int value new
```

Comment: This all depends on how the created objects are stored - you could use the object's name as a key in std::map, or use std::list and use std::find_if to search the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a static STD::map as a private member of ObjectA class. And also have a static Getter to query this map depending on key value.

Also one more thing do populate this map in your CTOR, this will ensure that you are not losing any object from getting registered to this static map.